# Can I specify multiple possible sources for a ccnet statistic?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config, dotcover

I have some builds that use NCover for test coverage analysis, and some that use DotCover.  I merge the NCover/DotCover summary report into the ccnet log, but the item that I need to pull out into the ccnet "Coverage" statistic is different depending on the tool (because the format of the reports are different).

For NCover, I use the following:

```
    <statistics>
      <statisticList>
        <firstMatch name="Coverage"
                    xpath="//coverageReport/project/@coverage"
                    generateGraph="true" />
      </statisticList>
    </statistics>
```

For DotCover, I need this:

```
    <statistics>
      <statisticList>
        <firstMatch name="Coverage"
                    xpath="//Root/@CoveragePercent"
                    generateGraph="true" />
      </statisticList>
    </statistics>
```

Is there any way to specify both?  If I just list both sections inside the statisticList, the second one always wins (so if I list DotCover second, builds that use NCover have their coverage stat set to zero, because the DotCover stat can't be found).  What I want is for the stat to get set to the NCover stat if it exists, or to the DotCover stat if it exists.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do an OR in the xpath expression, for example:

```
<statistics>
  <statisticList>
    <firstMatch name="Coverage"
                xpath="//Root/@CoveragePercent | //coverageReport/project/@coverage"
                generateGraph="true" />
  </statisticList>
</statistics>
```